# Thumbnail in iOS SDK feed dialog not appearing (appears as "?")

Tags: ios, facebook, thumbnails, feed

The problem is that in the feed dialog - we see a ? for the thubmnail rather than an actual thumbnail image.

Our application creates panoramic content which can be viewed on the web.
On desktop/laptop web browsers - the content is packaged as a SWF.
On mobile safari - we use HTML5.
The default web page (index.html) automatically redirects to the IOS specific version of the page if the safari mobile browser is detected.

We wish to post links to this web content on Facebook via a dialog (so the user can preview the post).
After the post is complete and it is being viewed:

1. In the mobile versions of the facebook application - we want the users to see

   - a thumbnail (and other descriptive text).
   - if they click on the thumbnail - it should open another browser page with the HTML5 content.
2. In the non-mobile-safari web versions of facebook - we want the user to see a SWF thumbnail with a play icon - and if they click the icon the page loads in the wall.

I have already made a number of changes to the app, including:

1. Changed the generated pages on the server to include the OG (Open Graph) meta tags. The page I modified now passes the developer lint tool. If I attempt to post a link to this page from the website - the thumbnail is determined automatically (as expected).
2. I switched from using the dialog "stream.publish" to "feed" and I now provide the new set of arguments expected - including "source" (the SWF URL) and "picture" (the URL of the thumbnail).

Here is the current set of parameters to the feed dialog:

```
    Printing description of params:
    <CFBasicHash 0x6a790a0 [0x3fdd69f8]>{type = mutable dict, count = 8, entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x118f50 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "link"} = <CFString 0x6a79080 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "http://media.demodev.everyscape.com/TOURX/503/3023503/INDEX.HTML"}
1 : <CFString 0x117970 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0x118f20 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "Virtual tour created using free UScapeit app"}
3 : <CFString 0x118f90 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "caption"} = <CFString 0x118f80 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "Explore this place"}
4 : <CFString 0x117880 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x272250 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "ES Cnxn test Dev"}
5 : <CFString 0x118f60 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "picture"} = <CFString 0x6a78e80 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "http://media.demodev.everyscape.com/TOURX/503/3023503/TOUR.THUMBNAIL.JPG"}
8 : <CFString 0x118f30 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "api_key"} = <CFString 0x116cf0 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "154419894617497"}
9 : <CFString 0x118f40 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "user_message_prompt"} = <CFString 0x6a78e10 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "What do you think of the Scape ES Cnxn test Dev?"}
10 : <CFString 0x118f70 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "source"} = <CFString 0x6a79020 [0x3fdd69f8]>{contents = "http://media.demodev.everyscape.com/TOURX/503/3023503/TOUR.SWF"}
```

}

Finally - I have a) researched the documentation (to make the changes I made above), and b) researched existing questions/answers - including the following:

- [iOS SDK posting a link & displaying a thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509838/ios-sdk-posting-a-link-displaying-a-thumbnail)

If anyone can tell me how to modify the client and/or server sides of this application to see the thumbnail image in the feed dialog, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Chuck

Comment: It appears that I have a choice: 1) provide parameter "source" (and "picture" - otherwise I get an error) and get no thumbnails in the feed dialog or in facebook on the iOS devices - but I do get in wall playing of our SWF content in other web browsers (on the Facebook site), or 2) provide just "picture" and get thumbnails in the feed dialog and in all Facebook applications/websites (but no in-wall playing of SWF content). Since it forces me to pass the "picture" parameter too - it would be nice if I could do both. The doc says that if you provide both - source is used and picture is ignored.

Comment: SWF content is hard to display- just got this to work with a JS/SDK solution on the web. In iOS, you should use the same feed story parameters- that is source. So in your example, I don't see you using source. This is the example I got working: (view source of) http://www.banane.com/fb_flash_embed.html

Comment: Also, "user_message_prompt" isn't something. You want to use an dictionary that is "actions". See documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/